# Disable auto-complete of quotes and parenthesis in the latest Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded the [latest Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), the 6th one down the page.

I've looked at other questions/answers on StackOverflow and other websites for how to disable the auto-completion of quotes and parenthesis [ meaning, when you type a " and you get "", or you type a ( and you get () ], and none of these earlier solutions are findable in this latest eclipse. And digging around in the Window -> Preferences, I can't find how to turn it off either.

Can you please assist me and take a look, and let me know how to turn off this rather FRUSTRATING :-) ""feature?""

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the preferences ***TextMate > Language Configurations*** select the content type (probably, `org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.js`) and in the ***Auto Closing Pairs*** tab bellow uncheck the checkbox ***Enable auto closing brackets*** at the bottom.

Comment: Awesome, it worked, THANK YOU!  Hey Bro, a gift for you.  Death is solved, and all lack, limitation, please keep on eye out for www.aWorldWithoutLimits.rocks and www.AllWell.world.  Literally all problems are solved.  Just put a note out on your table somewhere, or in your phone calendar, so you check back every week or two. IT IS THE BEST NEWS EVER, EVER, EVER, EVER. Blessings and thanks, @howlger - I'm making my own javascript interactive player rather than use YouTube, etc., it's too ... ... passive, non-involved, guess where all good comes from?  ... that's right, you